# Add Advanced Custom Field to Woocommerce My Account Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add a ACF to the woocommerce front end 'My Account' page.

I've created the field, called it 'vat_number' and managed to add it to the User Edit Screen on the backend of the website.

I'm trying to add this field to the Edit Address front end screen on Woocommerce.

I've tried adding the following to the 'My-address.php' template, but it doesn't work

```
<?php the_field('vat_number', $user_id); ?>
```

But it's not working, does anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does the $user_id need to be the id of the current logged-in user? If so, you need to get the user ID first.

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
the_field('vat_number', $user_ID);
```

Comment: No It needs to be the Vat Number of the usser, doesn't have to be the logged in one

Comment: Where is the $user_id coming from? Does the $user_id need to be dymanic or are you hard-coding it? For example, if you have a user in your user DB with an ID of 3 and you use <?php the_field('vat_number', 3); ?>, then the Vat Number for user with ID of 3 will be outputted. If this needs to be dynamic, you'll need to figure out how to retrieve the necessary user ID.

Comment: The user ID is the id of the woocommerce customer whose account it is. The same way you can view a customers Address that THEYVE typed in. If that makes sense

Comment: Right, but the solution here is that you need to pass an actual user ID into the variable $user_ID. This alone: <?php the_field('vat_number', $user_id); ?> will output nothing since you haven't passed a value into $user_id. For example, if you set a variable $user_id = 3 and then write <?php the_field('vat_number', $user_id); ?>, it will output the Vat number for the user whose ID is 3. So before you use <?php the_field('vat_number', $user_id); ?>, you need to write a variable to find your user ID. Can you post the full code for this page?